# Why is my sort function say it’s not sort functio?

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
let fruits; 

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
     fruits=prompt(“What is your top 5 fruits?”)

fruits.sort(); 

console.log(fruits)
}
```

Comment: `prompt()` returns a string. You cannot call `.sort()` on strings but on arrays. You need `fruits` to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `array` to use `sort()`.
Here's how to do it :

```js
var fruits = []; 
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
     fruits.push(prompt('What is your top 5 fruits?'))
}

fruits.sort(); 

console.log(fruits)
```